# Finding $(this) selected value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Can't work this out...

I've got a `.change` event handler for multiple select boxes.  I need to find the selected value each time.  I can't work out how to use `.val` with `$(this)`.

So here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select.className").change(function() {

    //console.log($(this).val);
    //console.log($("option:selected",this).val);
  })
})
```

Both of the above return a function, and not the selected value I am looking for.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like everything else in jQuery, `val` is a function.
You need to call the function, like this: `$(this).val()`.

Comment: You beat me to it. I'll remove mine :(      :D

Answer (score 9):

.val is a method rather than a property. You will need to call it with parens:

```
//console.log($(this).val());
//console.log($("option:selected",this).val());
```